# Zombie process/Dyno on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have some zombie dyno/process running on the app. It's generating an issue that I can't see because it's not generating logs. The process is executing the delayed jobs of Ruby on Rails.

I want to kill it but I can't.
I tried the following solutions that I read on google.
The following commands without good results:

```
heroku ps:kill
heroku ps:stop
heroku ps:restart
```

I also use the functionality of restarting all dynos from the UI.
I tried disabling the dynos (setting them to zero).
I also tried removing the dyno from Procfile, deploying, and reverting the changes.
I tried to kill it using the bash and "kill PID" command.

Any of those solutions worked for me.

What can I do to kill that zombie process?

Comment: I just spent days debugging a bug that didn't exist, and was only there because Heroku is running a zombie Dyno for me. Amazing.